# Limited characters for <p>

Tags: javascript, html, css

What could be the shortest way to limit characters on HTML < p >? I'm thiking to make the element input, and remove border, background etc. to looks like just pure text and maxlength = 5; But I want to know if there is another solution. thank you!

```
    let recipeNameShow = document.createElement('p');
    recipeNameShow.classList.add('fntColor');
    recipeNameShow.id = 'recipeNameShow';
    recipeNameShow.innerText = newRecipeName;
```

Comment: As I think this is only for display (no user input) since you are asking about a <p> tag, @Grazielle Carvalho's answer is the best way to accomplish this and it doesn't require Javascript.
[Here's an article from CSS-Tricks about this.](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't expecting user input you can use `substr`:

```
let recipeNameShow = document.createElement('p');
recipeNameShow.classList.add('fntColor');
recipeNameShow.id = 'recipeNameShow';
recipeNameShow.innerText = newRecipeName.substr(0,5);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use JS you can use substr method like below.

```
    function cropText(_el, _len) {var element = document.querySelector(_el);
    var truncated = element.innerText;

if (truncated.length > _len) {
    truncated = truncated.substr(0,_len) + '...';
}
return truncated;} document.querySelector('p').innerText = cropText('p', 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a few options. to use input element, you can make its border: none.
https://jsfiddle.net/b8pn1wf7/1/ and if you want to make the input editable, you can have a little border to indicate where the input element is.

```html
<input id="test_input" class="plain-input" maxLength=5>
```

```js
const newRecipeName = "hello-world"
document.getElementById("test_input").value = newRecipeName.substring(0, 5);
```

```css
.plain-input {
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
}

.plain-input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border: 1px dotted #333;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its only to display lesser content, you can put a line-clamp on CSS. This way, it will limit the amount of lines of your content. The code is right bellow:

```css
div {
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p {
     -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Nam quis aliquet purus, ac suscipit eros. Mauris tincidunt faucibus nisl, a consectetur sapien molestie et. Morbi condimentum nibh sit amet auctor pulvinar. Phasellus fringilla ex ut est convallis, nec dictum augue vestibulum. Sed interdum felis in arcu convallis, id tincidunt massa imperdiet. Fusce tellus elit, viverra eu pellentesque vel, interdum in eros. Ut eget arcu quis dui congue mollis eu non justo. Nam elit sem, semper eget rutrum eget, semper quis lectus. Aliquam pellentesque in elit at facilisis. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Sed velit ante, imperdiet vestibulum rhoncus nec, mattis sed augue. Proin suscipit pharetra accumsan. In at mollis ligula. Cras nisi ex, hendrerit quis mi in, eleifend accumsan nunc. Aliquam erat volutpat. Vestibulum sit amet enim ullamcorper, pellentesque est consectetur, volutpat libero.</p>
</div>
```